# How to define VALUE and TO

Tags: forth, 6502

I want to implement the Forth words `VALUE` and `TO` on a RPC/8 (an emulated computer in a [Minecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_%28video_gaming%29)). My best attempts get me a set of words that work fine so long as I don't use them while compiling. More sepecificly `VALUE` works, but `TO` does not.

```
: VALUE CREATE , DOES> @ ;
: TO ' 3 + ! ;
```

I have tried everything I can think of to get it working and my best attempt gets me this:

```
['] NameOfAValue 3 + !
```

Note that the processor is not a pure 6502 but a [65EL02](http://ibm5100.net/redpower/6502-primer/), a custom variant of the [65816](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDC_65816/65802).

EDIT #1: Somehow I forgot the call to CREATE in value. It should have been there all along.
EDIT #2: I also got `3` and `+` switched around in TO... oops. It should have been the other way all along.

Comment: Blimey. A question about FORTH running on an emulated computer architecture on top of an emulated variant of a variant of a 6502 inside a game. I can't answer it, but +1 just for the meta-meta-ness of it!

Comment: @Jonners Minecraft (for the PC) is written in Java so all of that is running in a virtual machine too.

Comment: @Milo; The code listed here for TO is still wrong Milo. ! is ( a n -) not ( n a -).  TO is trying to store a stack underflow to address 3.  It needs to be `: TO ( n) ' 3 + !`

Comment: @Brian Tiffin; Thanks, I don't know how I missed that. Its a typo, the code on my disk image is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok After a lot of trial and error as well as much searching I found something that should work, but because of two bugs in redFORTH, does not.

VALUE

```
\ Works fine, now to reset the value.
: VALUE \ n <name> --
    CREATE ,
    DOES> @
;
```

TO

```
\ Works if not compiling, LITERAL and POSTPONE are broken.
: TO
    TIBWORD FIND 3 +
    STATE @ IF
        POSTPONE LITERAL
        POSTPONE !
    ELSE
        !
    THEN
; IMMEDIATE
```

Demo of bug in LITERAL

```
\ fails, very wierd error.
: TESTLIT [ 42 ] LITERAL ;
\ TESTLIT Unknown Token: TESTLIT
\ FORGET TESTLIT Unknown Token: TESTLIT
\ WORDS TESTLIT COLD SORTMATCH ...
```

Demo of bug in POSTPONE

```
\ fails, postpone is directly equivelent to [']
: TESTPOST POSTPONE + ; IMMEDIATE
: TEST 2 2 TESTPOST . ;
\ . 1935
\ ' + . 1935
```

I'm off to file a bug report....

EDIT #1: After some more trial and error and not a little swearing (I'm not good with FORTH) I found a way to make it work.

```
: TO
    TIBWORD FIND 3 +
    STATE @ IF
        (lit) (lit) , , \ store address
        (lit) ! ,
ELSE
        !
    THEN
; IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is

```
VARIABLE TO-MESSAGE   \ 0 : FROM ,  1 : TO .
0 TO-MESSAGE !        \ needed to initialise the variable
         
: TO 1 TO-MESSAGE ! ;

: VALUE CREATE , DOES> TO-MESSAGE @ IF ! ELSE @ THEN 
    0 TO-MESSAGE ! ;
```

It uses only CORE words and is absolutely standard.
And it just works in interpret and compile mode, because there is no fishy look ahead in the input stream.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how your Forth handles interpreting versus compile time, but the definition of TO is trying to store a value to address 3.  Seems fishy.

Comment: 3 is the offset from the xt where the value created by CREATE is. I found this out via expermentation, too bad there is no word defined to get this offset in a portable way (in redFORTH, there is in other forths)

Comment: Excuse the double post, it took longer than 5 minutes to find the code formatting trick for comments. Backtick, shoulda guessed.  That comment above should read...  Milo, sorry, but the word order looks wrong.  Try `' word 3 + !`  What I see in your TO definition is; tick a word, add whatever else was on the stack at the time, store that value to address 3.

Comment: Follow up on an other answer? That is where comments are for.

Comment: Down voted. This is not an answer, let alone an answer to the question.